# Error: Can't find linux version string in kernel image file

Tags: android-studio, linux-kernel, android-virtual-device

I'm setup my sdk location in project structure and also set environmental variable. BUT important thing is that system uses wrong path, it uses backward slashes "\" instead of forward slashes "/".
Pls see uploaded image and specially see slashes.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qax3w.png)